# $R$-module structure on finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules, abelian-groups

> Which commutative rings $R$ have the property that there exists a finite non-trivial abelian group $G$ that admits an $R$-module structure?

Any counterexample?

Comment: @Shoutre What do you mean by "trivial"? If the ring is unital, there is not really a natural way to define that.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Right.

Comment: In the definition of R-module i want 1g=g for all g in G so in particular R should have a 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume $R$ has $1$, otherwise the task is trivial.

Suppose $G$ is a nonzero finite $R$-module. Then, if $g\in G$, $g\ne0$, $gR\ne0$ and $gR$ is finite. Thus $R/\operatorname{Ann}_R(g)$ is a finite ring.

So the answer is: if and only if $R$ has an ideal of finite index, which of course is equivalent to “$R$ has a maximal ideal $I$ such that $R/I$ is a finite field”.