# Is every abelian group $(M,+)$ an $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups

The idea is to show or give a counterexample to the affirmation that any abelian group can be turned to an $R$-module, for any ring $R$.

Let $R$ be any ring with $1$, and $(M,+)$ be an arbitrary abelian group.

Does there exist a ring morphism $\psi:R\to{\rm End}(M,+)$?

This question is just out of curiosity, if ${\rm End}(M,+)$ is isomorphic to a ring $S$ such that there are no ring homomorphisms from $R$ to $S$, then we would have a counterexample to the proposition, but it does not seem as if that were the case, since $R$ and $M$ are completely arbitrary...

Comment: Consider e.g. $R=\mathbb{Q}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}$. (I think this has been asked before ...)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056012/r-module-structure-on-finite-group?rq=1) is also related.

Comment: Since the answer making this point has been deleted, can I just point out that Martin Brandenburg's answer is assuming that your $R$-modules are *unital*, that is they satisfy $1 \cdot m = m$ for all $m \in M$. It seems likely that you were also assuming that, because otherwise you can trivially make $M$ into an $R$-module by defining $r \cdot m = 0$ for all $r \in R$, $m \in M$.

Answer (score 8):

No. For example, an abelian group $A$ admits a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-module structure if and only if $nA= 0$. It admits a $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]$-module structure if and only if $n : A \to A$ is an isomorphism. It admits a $\mathbb{Q}$-module structure if and only if it is divisible and torsionfree.

Comment: Indeed. At the same time, it may be worth mentioning (one of at least two) ways of naturally converting $\mathbb Z$-modules $M$ to $R$-modules, namely, $M\otimes_{\mathbb Z}R$...